# Does destructor in C++ automatically deallocates memory of the declared pointer variables inside the class?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Suppose I have a following Class:

```
   class foo{

   int array_allocation(int length){

          array= new int[length];
          return 0;

   }
   private:
      int *array;

   };
```

Here should I need to implement `~foo(){ delete []array};` or its implicitly done??

Comment: [Yes you need to deallocate it yourself.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Use `std::vector` and you won't have to worry. To respond to Mysticial's link, [Rule of Zero](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html).

Comment: You need to do it manually. But there is a lot more involved than just writting a destructor (that is not enough). You need to apply the rule of three (five). But the standard containers already manage memory for you when you need multiple values. Use `std::vector<int> array;`

Comment: Yes...you would use std::vector<int> instead of an array, but the question is not, what is best to use, the question is about the memory management of objects. What if the OP had been allocating something else as an example?

Comment: in some of my member functions I declared arrays which depen on the calculated size, so I used new operator.Could I use simply int array[calculted_size] declaration instead?..as I have used new operator I should deallocate memory at the end when the funtion returns right?...I was interested on arrays more than vectors for the reason that they are faster, so I want to stick to arrays

Comment: most of my classes I needed to declare a dynamic array as a private variable and member funtions actually allocates them by themselves, what should be the common structure of a copy constructor and assignment operator for that?

Comment: While using copy constructors is it needed to copy other member variables which are not dynamically allocated?

Answer (score 4):

Neither, you should use `std::vector<int>` instead. I'm not even talking as a member of your class, but *instead* of your class.

EDIT: no, the memory is not freed automatically. You need to provide a meaningful destructor, copy constructor & assignment operator.

Comment: whilst I fully understand and respect your answer, the question is about memory management. The question does not directly relate to the use of arrays (and as you quite rightly pointed out, vectors), and in that respect, the memory management of an array. What if class foo had been allocating something else?

Comment: @activwerx when I answered, there already was an answer covering that part (deleted now), that's why I skipped it.

Comment: Fair play! I just wanted to be sure! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are not automatically deleted.  Also when that class is copied the pointer is copied not the memory.  You should observe the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) design pattern and [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).